# Why am I getting this error? Error: invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++

Hi When I am running this peice of code, it shows this error ->

```
Error: invalid operands to binary expression
```

Please find below code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int number = cin>>"Enter your number";
    if(int number%2 == 0){
        cout<<"Even Number"<<endl;  
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Odd Number"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get the input from user. If I am hardcoding the value, it works.

Comment: `int number = cin>>"Enter your number";` makes no sense whatsoever. Where did you read that this is how you take user input?

Comment: `std::cout << "Enter your number: "; int number; std::cin >> number;` The `if` is wrong too, remove the `int` before `number`.

Comment: In what book have you seen such syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure if I can best explain this, but i'll try.

### What is `std::cin`?

`std::cin` is a C++ function that reads input into "somewhere else"

That "Somewhere" is usually variable. It will then proceed to read the input into that variable.

For Example:  `cin >> Character` Would read the input into the Variable `Character`

### The First Problem

---

You're first problem is trying to read input with a string , which you probably didn't intend on doing that.
If you want to output something use `std::cout`.

### The Second Problem:

---

The *module operator* doesn't not support integers, but doubles, i believe.
I may be wrong about that.

Also, you defined a new number in the if statement:
`if(int number%2 == 0)`

The reason why it is wrong is because *you're declaring another variable*, which is certainly what you do not want.

So you can fix this by simply removing that:

`if (number % 2 == 0)`

---

### The Corrected Version

---

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter your number: "; // We don't want a new line
    double number;
    cin >> number; //read input into the number
    if(number%2 == 0){ //does it equal zero?
        cout << endl << "Even Number"<< endl;  
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "Odd Number"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the int here also: `if(int number % 2 == 0)`